# when I Installed Python on Windows and it doesn’t configure the path

Tags: python

When i entered the code its showing this error as I attached on picture.

[image: Environment]

::SetEnvironment

```
Variable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

You have to add python env path manualy.

Follow this tutorial: [How to add Python to PATH in Windows 10](https://www.configserverfirewall.com/windows-10/add-python-to-path-windows-10/)

Or simply reinstall python but on the customization screen, scroll down, click “Add python.exe to Path,” and then select “Will be installed on local hard drive.” When you’re done, click “Next.”